# RETURNING clauses works in pgAdmin but returns -1 for my Java code

Tags: java, postgresql, dropwizard, pgadmin, jdbi

I have two tables that I am trying to insert a row to. Connected by a foreign key. I am using java 8 postgres 9.5.4.

I have tried using the RETURNING clause which works while in pgAdmin (values >= 1) but when run in using my java app. the value is then set to -1 and an error is thrown.

This is my working query for pgAdmin,

```
INSERT INTO counting_table (count1, cout2) 
VALUES (3, 2) RETURNING id
```

this returns the proper value in pgAdmin, but when entered as,

```
@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO counting_table (count1, count2) " +
            "VALUES (:count1, :count2) " +
            "RETURNING id")
    int insertCountingTable(@Bind("count1") int count1,
                            @Bind("count2")int count2);

@CreateSqlObject
@Override
public void add(Person person, int count1, int count2)
{
    try(Handle handle = jdbi.open())
    {
        PersonDao personDao = handle.attach(PersonDao.class);
        int id = personDao.insertCountingTable(count1, count2);

        personDao.insertPerson(person.getPersonId(),
                person.getName(), id);
    }
}
```

When the line

```
int id = personDao.insertCountingTable(count1, count2);
```

is executed the id is set to -1 but the value should be >= 1,
also checking the database I see that the row has been successfully inserted.

Comment: Do you see the record inserted into the table successfully or not?

Comment: Yes the record is inserted into the each time. I should have menchened that, thank you @Nicarus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get the `RETURNING` clause to work the way that I wanted to but using the `@GetGeneratedKeys` annotation above my query and removing the `RETURNING` line, I was able to achieve the desired results.

My code now looks as such,

```
@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO counting_table (count1, count2) " +
"VALUES (:count1, :count2)")
@GetGeneratedKeys
int insertCountingTable(@Bind("count1") int count1,
                        @Bind("count2")int count2);
```